# Battery voltage and ABS system

Tags: honda, battery, abs

I have 2000 Honda HRV GH 3.
I scanned my vehicle, It shows ABS System Failure, Battery Voltage Failure.
Last year I changed the battery, it's a 45AH battery, 
A mechanic said to change to a battery with 55Ah to solve this issue, is it possible I need a new battery?

Comment: Hi, this isn't how we ask questions, I've made some edits, some more information would be required. Which engine? Do you have trouble starting? What is the battery voltage with engine off and at idle? We can check what the correct battery is using online checkers with trim and engine information.

Comment: Honda 1.6cc LEV Engine

Comment: Not Trable to start....

Comment: Never check to battery voltage with engine off and at idle

Answer (score 2):

This failure code is stored in most Honda's that we scan. Usually it is code 61-1. It comes from low voltage during cranking. The codes do not erase themselves so all it takes to have the code is one event where the battery was low on charge during cranking.

Erase all trouble codes in the module and then recheck for new codes. If none come back then there is no need for repairs. Any codes that comes back after clear needs to be investigated. If it does not then no action is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the battery is the correct size for the vehicle - perhaps your mechanic is correct. Then, check the charging system, after that investigate the other faults.

Comment: Battery is correct size

Comment: Then check the charging system, after that investigate the other faults.